# How can I get notifications from Mailchimp's webhook API when I import contacts?

Tags: mailchimp, webhooks, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I wanted to synchronize my contacts from mailchimp to my app.
I did this by periodically asking Mailchimp if any contacts were updated or created .

Now, I want to do it using the Mailchimp's webhooks.

I have created a webhook in mailchimp and tested it and it works well when I do some changes as Admin using the Mailchimp UI, but when I add or update any contacts using import contacts functionality, I don't receive any notifications.

Mailchimp's webhook API says that they send notifications only when a change is made

- by a subscriber
- by an account admin
- via the API

so, since I'm not getting the notifications I used to get using the previous method, is changing to webhooks a bad option?

Is there any way that I could get the notifications I used to get from my old method, using Mailchimp's webhooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webhooks may have been omitted from imports to try and protect users from inadvertently DDoSiNg the hook destinations on large imports.

In regards to keeping these two data sets in parity, because webhooks don't have a trigger for import events, I might first suggest exploring another update method for adding subscriber data to the list in MailChimp.

Perhaps looking to the Batch operation options in MailChimp's API:

- http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/batches/
- http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/how-to-use-batch-operations/?utm_source=mc-api&utm_medium=docs&utm_campaign=apidocs&_ga=1.112643975.2008383502.1487629834

As this should allow large updates while keeping the external app abreast of any updates via the triggered webhooks.